# Calculate $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$ using contour complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

How can be shown that $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx=\frac{1}{i}\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}^{+}} \frac{dz}{z}$? (I know this expression to be true.)

The obvious parametrization of the arc $\partial \mathbb{D}^{+}$ would be
$$\gamma:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{C}, ~ t \mapsto e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}(t+1)}.$$

Then we would need to find a complex function $f(z)$, so that
$$\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}^{+}} f(z) dz = \int_{-1}^1 f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} dt,$$
but such a function cannot be $f(z)=\frac{1}{iz}$, or can't it?

Comment: (Missing a right-brace in the exponent was causing the TeX to not display properly...)

Comment: Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $z=x+i\sqrt{1-x^2}$ with $x \in [-1,1]$. Then

$$\frac{dz}{dx}=1-i\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}-ix}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \; .$$

And thus,

$$\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}^{+}} \frac{dz}{z} = \int_{-1}^{+1} \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}-ix}{x+i\sqrt{1-x^2}} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \frac{1}{i}\int_{-1}^{+1} \frac{x+i\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x+i\sqrt{1-x^2}} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \; .$$